# Which oil to "burn" (with a hot air gun) a rattan recurve

Tags: gear-care, archery

I've a rattan recurve bow here which needs to be tuned. However, I'm not sure which oil to use.

Which oil should I use to "burn" (with a hot air gun) a rattan recurve?

Answer (score 2):

For bending curves in the bows I have made, I have always just used a light coat of cooking oil.  Mineral oil should work as well, but it would cost more I think.